# Double associative entity in a business environment involving Order Item Reviews?

Tags: database-design

Suppose you have *Item* (**item_id**, item_name) and *Order* (**order_id**, user_id, order_date) entities, with primary keys denoted in bold. Because an order can consist of multiple items, and an item can be present in multiple orders, there's a many-to-many relationship between these entities that's normally broken down by inserting an additional associative entity between them, in this case *Item–Order* (**item_id**, **order_id**, item_count) with an additional attribute, and splitting the many-to-many relationship into two one-to-many relationships.

So far we have the following:

- *Item* (**item_id**, item_name)
- *Order* (**order_id**, user_id, order_date)
- *Item–Order* (**item_id**, **order_id**, item_count)

Suppose further that (a) a user can review each received item from their order, (b) providing a review is optional --i.e. the user may or may not enter a review-- and (c) a user can provide at most one review per item. Is it advisable to create the following additional entity type?

- *Review* (**item_id**, **order_id**, grade, comment_content, comment_date),

or would it be more customary to subsume it under *Item-Order*, in which case we'd obtain the following:

- *Item–Order* (**item_id**, **order_id**, item_count, grade, comment_content, comment_date)?

Of course, the latter would allow for the possibility of NULLs, and to me it doesn't look entirely conceptually sound.

Would the former be the better option if we were to generate an additional attribute, id_review, and declare it as primary key in the *Review* relation?

---

**Further details**

I imagined the scenario as a one-shot thing. A person places an order which contains multiple items. Once they've received their items, they can leave a review in which they'd first have to grade (say, out of 5) the items they received in order to leave a comment. If they don't leave a comment, it's stored as an empty string to which they can't make any further changes. They can leave a single review per type of item they've received, per order (meaning even if they've ordered multiple items of the same kind in the same order – they'll still be able to leave one review).

Comment: Hi. In true ER, associative entity types are 1:1 with relationships aka associations.That's why they are called "associative" entity types. In pre-ER methods falsely called ER, only entity types are explicit, their M:M:etc relationships are implicit & the 1:M relationship associated with a line/FK is the binary one that maps the referencing associative entity type to the referenced entity type that is derived from the former's implicit relationship. Your M:M relationship isn't "split into two 1:M relationships"; it is the implicit relationship of the Item-Order associative entity type.

Comment: The 2nd Item-Order is the invertible left join of the 1st Item-Order & Review. The 2-table design has straightforward declarative constraints. There's not much to choose between the designs. There's no particular reason for adding a surrogate key. PS "doesn't look entirely conceptually sound" is not clear or helpful. You might get some help if you were clearer. PS Please clarify via post edits, not comments.